# Insertion Sort - TStringList Delphi

Tags: sorting, delphi, insertion, tstringlist

i'm trying to sort TStringList of integers from a text file with Insertion and Selection Sort .Selection Sort works ok , but the Insertion Sort doesnt work with my code . Can someone tell me where i'm wrong ? My 'numbers.txt' has 5000 lines of numbers. Thanks in advance

UPDATE : I have edited my code a bit , it works now with Insertion-Sort but it sorts just 4 indexes of integer as on the image

```
var
  i, Position, n: integer;
  Value: string;
begin
  n := Items.Count;
  for i := 1 to n - 1 do
  begin
    Value := Items[i];
    Position := i-1;
     while (Position >0) and (Items[Position]>Value) do
      begin
        Items[Position+1]:= Items[Position]  ;
        Position := Position -1 ;
        end;
        Items[Position+1] := Value;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You code won't even compile: a "then" is missing. It can neither work as a sort by insertion. This kind of sort is done while building the list on the fly, starting from an empty list, scanning for the right position for an item and insert it there or add it at the end of the list. Also, why not convert all the text to integers? Sorting will probably be faster but sort order is not the same except if all integers have same length and all left padded with zeros.

Comment: This expression is wrong: `if Position Done := true`

Comment: Use the debugger and work it out for yourself. Start with simple input data and gradually build it up.

Comment: Be sure to test with test sets in different orders. You will be surprised if the first value is among the largest ones. Use a small set, say '5', '2', '1' and step through the code with F8, following what the code is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data in the image is sorting exactly as it should, because you're sorting on string values, and based on the comparison you're making the order is perfect. `"1143"` falls exactly between the string values `"11413"` and `"11443"`, because the comparison is made character by character out to the length of the shortest of the values. `"1141" < "1143" < "1144"`, based on the first four characters of each string.

If you want an actual integer sort, then you need to convert the two values to integer before comparing them. Something like this should work (note I did not test your overall sort logic - I just used values that demonstrate the concept):

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes;

var
  i, Position, n: integer;
  Value: integer;
  Items: TStringList;
begin
  Items := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Items.DelimitedText := '1116,11170,11178,11206,1122,11221,11228';
    n := Items.Count;
    for i := 1 to n - 1 do
    begin
      Value := StrToInt(Items[i]);
      Position := i - 1;
       while (Position > 0) and (StrToInt(Items[Position]) > Value) do
        begin
          Items[Position + 1]:= Items[Position];
          Position := Position - 1 ;
        end;
        Items[Position+1] := IntToStr(Value);
    end;
    for i := 0 to Items.Count - 1 do
      WriteLn(Items[i]);
  finally
    Items.Free;
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

The output I got from the code above in a console window:

```
1116
1122
11170
11178
11206
11221
11228
```